# Checking for an overflow datetime value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query to check for an overflow in a DateTime value (above '9999-12-31'). But still it throws some overflow exception while running. What am I doing wrong?

**Code**

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN Dateadd(d,s.ClaimDelay,si.IssueDate) NOT IN (9999-12-31) THEN si.issuedate
       ELSE Dateadd(d,s.ClaimDelay,si.IssueDate)
   END
FROM SubscriptionIssues si
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions s ON s.Id=si.SubId
```

**Exception**

Adding a value to a 'datetime' column caused an overflow.

Comment: The overflow exception is probably occurring during Dateadd.  You need your check before performing Dateadd.

Comment: Additionally, if you are running a system that needs something close to 9998-12-31... you might have designed it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your case statement is apparently either adding so many days to `si.IssueDate` that the result is greater than **`Dec 31, 9999`**

Edit your code to something like this:-

```
SELECT CASE
       WHEN datediff(d,si.IssueDate,'9999-12-31')<s.ClaimDelay THEN si.issuedate
       ELSE Dateadd(d,s.ClaimDelay,si.IssueDate)
   END
FROM SubscriptionIssues si
LEFT OUTER JOIN Subscriptions s ON s.Id=si.SubId
```

Comment: Yes .. That is why i was doing a check whether the result datetime exceeding (9999-12-31) or not.

Comment: After including your code, Still I am getting the same exception message only.

Comment: @Deva the answer had a typo. `>` had to be `<`.

Comment: Great Solution. This is what I was looking for. Thank you both Stijin and Luv.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if adding to the date is an overflow, you can check if subtracting from the max date is smaller than the date you have.

```
declare @date date

set @date = '9995-01-01'

select
    case
        when dateadd(d, -1000, '9999-12-31') < @date then @date
        else dateadd(d, 1000, @date)
end
/* returns 9997-09-27 */

set @date = '9999-01-01'

select
    case
        when dateadd(d, -1000, '9999-12-31') < @date then @date
        else dateadd(d, 1000, @date)
end

/* returns 9999-01-01 */
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd move that code into the business layer for one.  A stored procedure isn't the place to do this.

However, if you really want it in the stored procedure, check the values prior to the select.  How are you getting a year > 9999?  You have a data problem, or a logic problem prior to this SELECT statement.